# Show posts and custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Helllo,

I want to show posts and custom post types , can I change post_type in query as array('post','custom_post_type')

```
function get_posts( $args = null ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'numberposts'      => 5,
        'category'         => 0,
        'orderby'          => 'date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'include'          => array(),
        'exclude'          => array(),
        'meta_key'         => '',
        'meta_value'       => '',
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
    );
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `post_type` as a string (single type) or an array (multiple types).

Example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'movie', 'book' )
);
```

`movie` and `book` above are Custom Post Types.

If you want all post types just:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'any'
);
```

The above retrieves any type except `revisions` and types with `exclude_from_search` set to true.

[More info here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
?>
```

If you want to fetch the WordPress posts you can write `post` in the `post_type` parameter. If you want to fetch the custom post type you can pass the name of the custom post type like `movies` or  `courses`, to match whatever your custom post type name is in WordPress.